# Use second argument for optional first argument if not provided in macro

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, arguments

I'm trying to construct a command with one optional and one mandatory argument and I'd like the default if the optional argument is not provided to be #2.

Why does this not work?  (error: `Illegal parameter number ...`)

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2][#2]{\label{#1}#2}
\begin{document}
\mycommand{mytext}
\end{document}
```

And what would be a way around it?

**EDIT:**
For clarification of my specific use case: I'm trying to define a command that passes a variable on as an option to an environment along those lines, where `myenv` can have options like `optionone=X` or `optiontwo=Y` so the default for the optional #1 should be `optionone=#2` (not literally #2).

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2][optionone=#2]{\begin{myenv}[#1]\input{#2}\end{myenv}}
```

Maybe there's generally a better approach?   (The environment definition I'm using is from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334342/repeating-labels-of-custom-environment).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

#### Classical method

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycommand}{\@dblarg\my@command}
\def\my@command[#1]#2{\label{#1}#2}
\makeatother
```

#### `xparse`

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{O{#2}m}{\label{#1}#2}
```

#### Your use case

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycommand}{O{optionone=#2}m}{%
 \begin{myenv}[#1]\input{#2}\end{myenv}%
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works with the very minimal example here, but I ran into this problem in the context of trying to pass options to an environment, so eventually I don't want the default `#1` to be *exactly* `#2` --- I don't think I understand the `\def\my@command[#1]#2` syntax, I tried: `\def\my@command[#1]option=#2{\label{#1}#2}` but that doesn't work ...

Comment: I've edited the question for clarification of the specific use case.   Also, could you explain the reason why the original solution doesn't work?

Comment: @jan That's the danger of asking XY-questions.

Comment: sorry :/  I was trying to keep it general and minimal ...

Comment: @jan OK, but that completely hides the aim. I added the code

Answer (score 3):

Here, `\mycommand` determines if there is 1 or 2 arguments, and passes the result off to `\mycommandaux`, which handles both arguments, whether repeated or not.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\newcommand\mycommand[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \mycommandaux{#2}{#2}%
  \else
    \mycommandaux{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\mycommandaux[2]{Arguments 1,2: [#1]\{#2\}}
\begin{document}
\mycommand{xyz}

\mycommand[xyz]{pdq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Trying to conform more to the OP's edited example

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\mycommand[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \mycommandaux{optionone=#2}{#2}%
  \else
    \mycommandaux{#1}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand\mycommandaux[2]{\detokenize{\begin{myenv}[#1]\input{#2}\end{myenv}}}
\begin{document}
\mycommand{ABC}

\mycommand[optiontwo=xyz]{pdq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great too, thank you!  egreg was a little faster and it's somewhat simpler (provided I use `xparse`) so I accepted his, but I appreciate your help ...