# Pass second argument as the default first argument in a newcommand

Tags: macros, default

I'm trying to do something along these lines:

```
\newcommand{\pcite}[2][#2]{( #1 \cite{#2} )}
```

I.e. make it so that, if an explicit argument is used, then use it, otherwise re-use the second argument as the first

The intended use is:

```
As \pcite{Author.etal} has stated
```

should result in

> As ( Author.etal [1] ) has stated

whereas

```
As \pcite[Author and Coauthor, 1999]{Author.etal} have stated
```

should result in

> As ( Author and Coauthor, 1999 [1] ) have stated

---

<sub>PS. This is simply a minimal example, unrelated to the actual command I'm writing.</sub>

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/485258/35864 from earlier today help?

Comment: mindblowing. same question same day. didn't come up in the suggestions. thanks.